# restrict shell command to only part of a line

Tags: substitute, macro, shell

In a file I'd like to replace some occurrences of triplets of 0 with F, 1 with E, ..., F with 0.  Only some, so I can't just pipe the whole file through a bash `tr` filter; I need a text editor to examine each occurrence.

This is to invert the grayscale colors in some 1990's HTML from light-on-dark to dark-on-light, #000 to/from #FFF, #222 to/from #DDD,... .

What almost works:  cursor to the first digit,
`! tr 0123456789ABCDEF FEDCBA9876543210`.  After that I can just hit dot to repeat.  **But** that also reverses any other digits on the line.  For example, it changes

`border: 2px solid #555;`

to

`border: Dpx solid #AAA;`

- Can I restrict the command to affect just the `555`?
- Or can I write a macro purely within vim that reverses this range of values, just like `tr`?
- Or can a command other than `tr`, applied to the whole line, limit its effect to `/#[0-9]{3}/`?  Maybe some `sed` magic?

(If the last of these three turns out to be the solution, then this question may be off topic here.)

Comment: The `!` filter unfortunately always works linewise, so you’d need some vimscript to handle grabbing the appropriate text, filter it, and put it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `:h :s\=`

```
s/\v\#[0-9A-F]{3}[0-9A-F]@!/\=tr(submatch(0), '0123456789ABCDEF','FEDCBA9876543210')/g
```

- `\#[0-9A-F]{3}` match `#000`, `#111`, ... `#FFF`
- `[0-9A-F]@!` look forward to make sure `#0000` doesn't match. check `:h /\@!`
- `\=` replace with an expression
- `tr(submatch(0), '0123456789ABCDEF','FEDCBA9876543210')` transform matching text

Since you want to do it manually, a command or map would help:

```
command InvertGrayScale s/\v\#[0-9A-F]{3}[0-9A-F]@!/\=tr(submatch(0), '0123456789ABCDEF','FEDCBA9876543210')/g

nnoremap <leader>ig :InvertGrayScale<cr>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i had in mind